# Django admin page login causing IIS to crash, need to restart iis everytime

Tags: django, iis, django-admin, iis-7.5

My site is working fine. I can access all the pages. But when I am accessing admin page, it loads, prompts for username and password. After entering username and password when clicked login, it takes sometimes and after that I get below error:

> This page isn’t working mytestapp.company.com didn’t send any data.
>   ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

After refreshing the page, I get below error:

> Service Unavailable HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.

After this no page loads. After restarting IIS using cmd (iisreset /noforce) again when I try to refresh the homepage, I see I am logged in which means admin page logged me in but after that response did not come and it something went wrong on the server side which caused server to crash.

I am not sure how to proceed with this. Earlier my admin site use to work fine. No recent changes in code. The only change I did is I synced the DB from another DB which has more data.

I am using virtual env which has
python version is 2.7.3, Django version 1.3 in it
IIS version 7.5 on WindowsServer 2008R2 (Python IsAPIe handler)

Please help me on this. I am stuck with this issue...

Comment: The developers of the admin page can easily assist you on that. Open a bug report to them.

Comment: Thanks Lex. Issue is resolved now. IIS service was getting stopped because of a series of error caused while rendering admin page. After checking windows event log and understanding error code, got to know that the Python-Runtime.dll which admin page was referring was having some issue. I replaced the dll with the previous working version and then everything started working fine.

Comment: you should post that as an answer and accept it.

Comment: Did it. I am new to stackoverflow. Thanks for guiding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is resolved now. IIS service was getting stopped because of a series of error caused while rendering admin page. After checking windows event log and understanding error code, got to know that the Python-Runtime.dll which admin page was referring was having some issue. I replaced the dll with the previous working version and then everything started working fine.